# Python нарисовать GUI для крестиков-ноликов

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

Как сделать поле для крестиков-ноликов и при клике на определенную ячейку нужно, что бы изменялось значение в моем словаре (который будет "базой" для крестиков-ноликов) и изменялся символ на крестик. При следующем клике так же изменится значение в моем словаре и символ на поле на нолик и так по кругу.

Просто прошу советов, которые помогут мне решить это задание, спасибо.

Comment: Раз вы уже все придумали (ТЗ поставлено), то какого рода советы вам нужны? Как рисовать массив ячеек, как отслеживать событие клика пользователя на ячейку, как менять символ внутри ячейки? Что конкретно из этого?

Comment: m9_psy, хотел бы получить совет, как отслеживать событие клика пользователя на ячейку, с остальным, думаю, сам разберусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда задайте отдельный конкретный вопрос с изолированной проблемой типа "Как отследить нажатие мыши на кнопку".

Answer (score 4):

Набросал простенький пример рисования доски и обработке клика на ее ячейках с изменением матрицы доски:

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *

except:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Матрица 3 на 3
        self._board_tic_tac_toe = [[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

        self._size_cell = 80

        # If True -- X else -- O
        self._current_figure_flag = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        # Определяем позицию клика
        i = e.pos().y() // self._size_cell
        j = e.pos().x() // self._size_cell

        # Выход за пределы массива
        if i >= 3 or j >= 3:
            return

        self._board_tic_tac_toe[i][j] = 'X' if self._current_figure_flag else 'O'
        self._current_figure_flag = not self._current_figure_flag

        # Перерисовка, вызов paintEvent
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)

        for i in range(len(self._board_tic_tac_toe)):
            row = self._board_tic_tac_toe[i]

            for j in range(len(row)):
                x = j * self._size_cell
                y = i * self._size_cell
                w = self._size_cell
                h = self._size_cell

                painter.drawRect(x, y, w, h)

                painter.save()
                painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 16))

                value = self._board_tic_tac_toe[i][j]
                painter.setPen(Qt.blue if value == 'X' else Qt.red)

                painter.drawText(x, y, w, h, Qt.AlignCenter, value)

                painter.restore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: gil9red, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Grzegorzg, пожалуйста :) На этом сайте благодарность принято выражать принятием ответа (галочка слева от ответа) и указанием что ответ полезен (стрелочка вверх от ответа)

Comment: @Grzegorzg, никогда не поздно принять ответ ;) :D

Comment: @Grzegorzg  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour